# How to issue commit after install gitlab on ubuntu

Tags: git, gitlab

I install gitlab on ubuntu server.

And add project to my gitlab.

after run `git push -u origin master` show this error:

How to fix this issue?

```
Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://example.com/user/project.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that your repository URL is https://example.com/user/project.git/, so that might be your first problem.

Comment: @Séb hi, this url is example

Comment: Where did you get the cert for your server?  How was it issued?  Was a suitable root cert added to your trust store?

Comment: @mySun If that url is an example itself, then you haven't provided enough information to diagnose your problem - we can't figure out the problem with that little information. You need to provide details about the certificate and the hosting mechanism for GitLab.